# Understanding the implications of STM32 pinout configuration conflicts (yellow triangles) in CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32, i2c, gpio, stm32cubemx, configuration

Using CubeIDE and configuring STM32L072 I get some (yellow triangle) GPIO conflicts on my I2C2 interface.  The GPIO's are assigned to other non I2C uses. Where would I look to understand the implication and meaning of such conflicts?

So far as I know I2C interfaces only require 2 pins and there are no configuration options to turn on or off for I2Cs.

I am concerned that this means that there may be timing conflicts with concurrent use of those conflicting GPIOs and I2C, or worse, something I don't understand yet.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot resolution is too small to see anything.

Comment: Yes .. not sure how that happened; thanks .. something to lookout for in future

Answer (score 2):

> Where would I look to understand the implication and meaning of such
> conflicts?

It most likely means you have other hardware that is assigned to the same pins. The problem with this is cube mx can't generate code if you are using two hardware devices (like a timer and I2C) for the same pins.

If you need to do sharing you'll have to write your own code and turn one hardware device on and the other one off.

So go through the list and find out what is also using those pins and decide which hardware device one you want the pins to use.

Comment: Thanks .. After going through the list I think I see that I2C1 can support SMBus that I was unfamiliar with (and not using) so it looks like a conflict but is really "potential conflict": a little confusing actually. Gaining experience as I go; thanks for your post.